# NaNs produced while converting factors to integers

Tags: r

I need code fix. I have data frame which consist non-numeric (`Var`) and numeric (`Var.num`) variables like this (one row):

```
    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var.num1    Var.num2    Var.num3
1   ABC      DEF    GHI     JKL        2010        2011        1.2
```

At least one of numeric variables is considered to be a `factor` (it may differ for each row)   and to make my other code work correctly ( no need of posting it here) I need to change all `factor` to `integer`, after quick research and adjustment I had something like this:

```
   newdf <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.integer(levels(x))[x] else x)
```

It worked perfectly for numeric variables (changed every `factor` left other, exactly what I wanted), but it produced `NaNs` for non-numeric so output looks something like this

```
    Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var.num1    Var.num2    Var.num3
1   #N/D!   #N/D!   #N/D!   #N/D!       2010        2011         1.2
```

Could you tell me what part of my code should be changes so non-numeric variables would same in output like in pre-transformed data frame?

Comment: maybe just `unclass(x)` for the `is.factor` branch?

Comment: `newdf <- lapply(df, function(x) if(unclass(is.factor(x))) as.integer(levels(x))[x] else x)`

Like this? It still produces `NaNs` same way as first code

Comment: Thing i forgot is to put exact error message:


`In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion`